# Call parent method from nested child in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

I scaffolded a project from `vue-cli` using the `webpack` template.

Now in the `App` component I created a bootstrap modal dialog, which I want to reuse from the entire application. Along with that I also created one method in the `App` component called `showMessage` which actually does the work of showing the modal.

Now considering that I should be able to reach that method from any component, is calling like what is shown below a bad idea?

```
this.$root.$children[0].showMessage('Message', `An email will be sent to ${this.form.email}`)
```

Comment: Using $root or $parent is always a bad practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a fragile way to handle global messaging.

At least register an event on the root component from inside the modal component:

```
methods: {
  showMessage(message) {
    // your code to display the message
  }
},
created() {
  this.$root.$on('showMessage', this.showMessage)
},
destroyed() {
  this.$root.$off('showMessage', this.showMessage)
}
```

Then you can use `this.$root.$emit('showMessage', 'foo message')` to display a message from anywhere within the scope of that root component.

---

Even better might be to create an event bus:

```
Vue.prototype.$bus = new Vue();
```

```
methods: {
  showMessage(message) {
    // your code to display the message
  }
},
created() {
  this.$bus.$on('showMessage', this.showMessage)
},
destroyed() {
  this.$bus.$off('showMessage', this.showMessage)
}
```

```
this.$bus.$emit('showMessage', 'foo message')
```

This way, you have a slightly better separation of concerns.

Comment: Awesome. This works like a charm. One quick question is should the event be named something like `app::showMessage` to just scope it for my app?

Comment: Yeah, that would make sense. Or you can create an event bus (see my edit)